# Node JS - merging objects by their keys where keys are not known

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a bunch of data that I fetch from a Mongo database.
To put it in simplified terms I have data that looks like this:

```js
var a = [{
  "F1": [
    "value1"
  ]
}];

var b = [{
  "8002": [
    "value3",
    "value4"
  ]
}];

var c = [{
    "F1": [
      "value1",
      "value3"
    ]
  },
  {
    '8002': [
      "value5"
    ]
  }
];

a = a.concat(b).concat(c);
console.log(a);
```

When I combine these  I get:

```
[
  { 'F1': ['value1'] },
  { '8002': ['value3', 'value4'] },
  { 'F1': ['value1', 'value3'] },
  { '8002': ['value5'] }
]
```

But what I need is:

```
[ 
   { 'F1': [ 'value1','value3' ] },
   { '8002': [ 'value3', 'value4','value5' ] }
]
```

Where the unique keys have their values merged.
How to achieve this is Node/JavaScript ?

Comment: These are JavaScript objects. JSON is a serialisation format where data is converted into *text*.

Comment: do you have always the same structure like array, object, single property with an array?

Comment: Why can't you extract necessary data structure from mongo directly?

Comment: I've re-wrote the question for some clarity and added a snippet.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes.. the structure is the same

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg I dont quite have the access to database.. someone else is sending the data to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the given arrays and check if the same key exist in the result set, then check if the values exists or not, then push the value to the result set.

```js
var a = [{ F1: ["value1"] }],
    b = [{ 8002: ["value3", "value4"] }],
    c = [{ F1: ["value1", "value3"] }, { 8002: ["value5"] }],
    result = [...a, ...b, ...c].reduce((r, o) => {
        var key = Object.keys(o)[0],
            temp = r.find(p => key in p);

        if (!temp) return r.concat(o);
        o[key].forEach(v => {
            if (!temp[key].includes(v)) temp[key].push(v);
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A Map with Sets.

```js
var a = [{ F1: ["value1"] }],
    b = [{ 8002: ["value3", "value4"] }],
    c = [{ F1: ["value1", "value3"] }, { 8002: ["value5"] }],
    result = Array.from(
        [...a, ...b, ...c].reduce((m, o) => {
            var [k, v] = Object.entries(o)[0];
            return m.set(k, new Set([...(m.get(k) || []), ...v]));
        }, new Map),
        ([k, v]) => ({ [k]: [...v] })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using `reduce()`

```js
var a =[ { "F1" : [ "value1" ] } ]; 
var b =[ { "8002" : [ "value3", "value4" ] } ]; 
var c =[ { "F1" : [ "value1", "value3" ] }, { '8002': [ "value5" ] } ];
    
let arr = [...a,...b,...c];

let res = arr.reduce((ac,a) => {
  let key = Object.keys(a)[0];
  ac[key] = (ac[key] || []).concat(a[key]);
  return ac;
})

res = Object.entries(res).map(([k,v]) => ({[k]:v}))

console.log(res)
```